# Convert urllib2 python code to use urllib module

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I have the following code below which runs using the urllib2 module, but I have a requirement to upgrade to Python 3.x and this prevents the use of urllib2. I am aware it is split across urllib.request and urllib.error, but I am struggling to convert the following code to use the urllib module instead after reading through the doc and other relevant questions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
  request = urllib2.Request(url=event['ResponseURL'], data=data)
  request.add_header('Content-Type', '')
  request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
  url = opener.open(request)
```

Comment: Just run `2to3` on that module and see what changes that made for you. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace `urllib2` with `urllib.request`. You are not using anything that has moved to other `urllib.*` modules:

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib.request.Request(url=event['ResponseURL'], data=data)
request.add_header('Content-Type', '')
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = opener.open(request)
```

You can always run the [`2to3` command-line tool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) on your Python 2 code and see what changes it makes; the default action is to output changes on stdout in unified diff format.

The `urllib` fixer will then also add imports for `urllib.error` and `urllib.parse` at the top, because it knows that code that imported `urllib2` *could* need any of the 3 `urllib.*` modules; it isn't smart enough to limit the import only to those that are actually needed after transforming the rest of the `urllib2` references in the module.

Comment: Works like a charm! However, am now getting this error: [8fc8f326-a615-4020-8364-9edbd81e4853][2019-02-01 15:47:15,741][ERROR] POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: @Sam: you'll have to encode your `data` variable to a suitable encoding. What encoding to use is entirely up to the specific data and what the server accepts. You set the `Content-Type` header to an empty string so I can't help you decide there.

Comment: Very useful! Sorted the Content-Type issue now, thanks for pointing them out.